# Error when sending emails using Nodemailer

Tags: html, node.js, express, undefined, nodemailer

server.js:

```js
app.post('/game',(req,res,next)=>{
    //if(!emailValidator(req.body.email)){
      // I would do email validations client side to but if you
      // want to do server side send some html saying the email is invalid
      //res.sendFile(invalidEmail.html)
    //}
    //else{
      //I assume you have some script for sending email. I'll use nodemailer cuz its the first
      //module I found
      let sender = 'myemail@gmail.com'
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'gmail',
        auth:{
          user:sender,
          pass:'Mypassword'
        }
      })
      let mailOptions = {
        from: sender,
        to: req.body.email,
        subject:'New sign up',
        text:'Thanks for subscribing'
      }
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error,info){
        if(error){
          // do somehting
          console.log(error)
        }
        else{
          console.log('Sent new user email')
          req.next()
        }
      })
    }
    //}
    )
```

index.html:

```html
<form action="game" method="post" size="30">
    <input type="text" name="email"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I'm having this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
```

So there is this error with my code, I'm trying to send an email with Nodemailer from a form in HTML, can someone help me fix this?

Also there is a part for email validation but I removed it as it says "emailValidator" is undefined.

Comment: Have you configured your Express instance's body parser? If so, can you edit your question to include this additional bit of code where you do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the main folder, create a public folder, inside it create an index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Simple page</title>
</head>

<body>
   <form action="game" method="post" size="30">
        <input type="text" name="email"/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Inside the main folder, create a server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
});


app.post('/game', (req, res) => {
    let senderUsername = 'example@gmail.com' // sender email address
    let senderPassword = 'password'; // senders password

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
         service: 'Gmail',
         auth: {
                user: senderUsername,
                pass: senderPassword
            }
        });

        const mailOptions = {
          from: senderUsername, // sender address
          to: req.body.email, // list of receivers
          subject: 'New sign up', // Subject line
          html: '<p>Thanks for subscribing.</p>'// plain text body
        };

        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, info) {
           if(err)
             console.log(err)
           else {
            console.log('Sent new user email')
            console.log(info);
            req.next() 
           }
    });
})

const PORT = 5000;

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`server running on PORT ${PORT}`)
})
```

Note :
You may also need to follow these steps while using a google account.

Enable the settings to allow less secure apps for the Gmail account that you are using.
Here is the link: [Google less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4Msk2qflnFUGh9-hxfmKoyzjh-_AgwmpXTbJMA4kNGy4RyCXKSYAk9DIDW-Hv-MxrxrwNAyYVyFadsiRvE2dcLVOO8Thg)

Allow access for "Display Unlock captcha option" (Allow access to your Google account)
Here is the link: [Google unlock captcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

You can also explore MailJet or SendGrid for sending emails.